# Why "ein Uhr" and not "eins Uhr"

Tags: expression

Why is it that "one o'clock" is `ein Uhr` and not `eins Uhr`? It is understandable that it's not `eine Uhr`, since we're not referring to one clock. But why is it that we're just using `ein` here?

Comment: More words using ein- instead of eins-: Einrad, Einbein(stativ), Einhorn, einäugig, einmal, einarm(ig), einstellig

Comment: @blutorange But each of your examples is one word, unlike `ein Uhr`, which is two words.

Comment: Counting usually uses "ein/eine" instead of "eins": ein Stuhl, zwei Stühle; eine Straße, zwei Straßen. OTOH, it's "ein Uhr", not "eine Uhr", and "zwei Uhr", not "zwei Uhren", so the question is what is actually counted here. Maybe some short form? "Ein Schlag der Uhr"? "One of clock", "two of clock" doesn't make a lot of sense at first glance, either. :-)

Comment: You say "einhundert" and not "einshundert" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use indeed "eins" (the number) here, not "ein" (the article). However, we [always inflect "eins"](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Kardinal.html#Anchor-eins-35326) when used for counting things.

Now the word "Uhr" is feminine -- according to [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Uhr) also in its function as time indicator. That would, indeed, mean we have to use "eine Uhr" here.

So why do we use "ein"?

The best explanation I can come up with is to think of "Uhr" here less as object but more as abstract concept, as a unit of time.

> Wie weit ist es noch? -- Einen Kilometer.
>
> Wie lang dauert die Vorstellung? -- Eine Stunde.
>
> Wie viel wiegt ein Liter Milch? -- Ein Kilogramm.

We see that even for units, "eins" is inflected properly by the gender of the unit it's attached to. So, apparently, we have implicitly defined a new unit:

> **Uhr**, Substantiv, neutrum
> Plural: ---

Note that we also ask, "Wie viel Uhr ist es?", as opposed to, "Wie viele ... ?", so "Uhr" is indeed properly uncountable (cf. "Wie viel Milch brauchst du?") -- but we still (kind of) count.

For what it's worth, this is not the only instance of using "Zahl + Singular"; consider

> Fünf Bier für die Männer vom Sägewerk!

Comment: I realise that this is not much of an answer but I hope it can offer some perspective. Maybe there is a technical term/rule for this but if so, neither do I know it nor could I find it. This may be a thing to accept and get used to.

Comment: Am Rande: Benutzt Du *Kilometer* als Neutrum?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Nein, "der Meter"; hab ich mich da wo vertan? Ah, "einen Kilometer", nicht wahr? Ups. Ich glaube, das wird oft verkürzt benutzt (also "ein Kilometer").

Comment: ja, das meinte ich, aber ich war nur neugierig. Nominativ wäre auch denkbar gewesen, und Nachschlagen hat mir verraten, dass *Kilometer* auch sächlich sein kann. Gesprochen sind *ein* und *einen* ohnehin nahe beieinander.

Comment: Das ist dann aber sehr wässrige Milch. :D Ein Liter Wasser wiegt ein Kilogramm. ;)

Comment: @Raphael: Die Verwirrung beim Kilometer dürfte daher kommen, dass die direkte Antwort "Es ist noch einen Kilometer weit." zwar grammatikalisch richtig, aber vollkommen unidiomatisch ist. Man versteht die Frage als "Wie groß ist die Entfernung zum Ziel?" und die übliche Antwort ist (zumindest im gesprochenen Deutsch, wo die Formulierung "beträgt" gestelzt wirkt) "Die Entfernung ist ein Kilometer.", oder eben kurz "Ein Kilometer."