# German time question ein vs eins

Tags: grammar

How would these work:

Is one o'clock ein Uhr or eins Uhr?

How does the capitalization work there?

Is 0:30 halb eins or halb ein?

Is 1:15 viertel nach eins or viertel nach ein?

Comment: Related: [Why “ein Uhr” and not “eins Uhr”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/12381/9551)

Comment: The part on capitalization is new and interesting (_es ist Eins_ vs. _es ist eins_ vs. _es ist ein Uhr_). Would you mind to edit your question to limit it to this aspect?

Answer (score 3):

As an example, your two options in German are:

> Es ist kurz vor ein Uhr.

or

> Es ist kurz vor eins.

So for your particular case:

> Es ist ein Uhr / Es ist eins.
>
> Es ist halb eins
>
> Es ist viertel nach eins.

You *would not* say:

> Es ist halb ein Uhr
>
> Es ist viertel nach ein Uhr

See https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Uhrzeit

Answer (score 0):

ein Uhr / zwölf Uhr dreissig / halb eins, viertel nach eins, viertel vor eins